# How to import VCL components from Borland C++Builder 6 to Embarcadero C++Builder?

Tags: c++, vcl, c++builder-6

I use C++Builder 6, but recently started using Embarcadero C++Builder.

In C++Builder 6, I have installed some VCL components, but some of them don't have support or upgrade for Embarcadero.

Does anyone know how to migrate these VCL components from C++Builder 6 to Embarcadero C++Builder if I have the `.cpp` files for them?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? If you have the source files for the components, what is stopping you from simply creating new packages for them in Embarcader C++Builder and re-compiling them? Please be more specific about what you actually need help with.

Comment: C++ Builder is Embarcadero C++ Builder. Borland became Codegear and sold the product to Embarcadero. You just recently upgraded from an ancient version to a newer version.